# Dozer seeks xml configs instead of Java confiigs

Tags: spring, mapper, dozer

I am working on a Spring Boot project with Spring Data Rest, Gradle and Oracle Express DB in which I use DozerBeanMapper to map entities to DTOs and vice versa, I use no xml configurations for Dozer, just Java ones:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DozerConfig {
    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapper getDozerMapper() {
        log.info("Initializing DozerBeanMapper bean");
        return new DozerBeanMapper();
    }
}
```

Also for clarity I have explicitly configured all the fields that has to be mapped although they are all with the same names. For example my Client mapper:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ClientMapper extends BaseMapper {

    private BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(Client.class, ClientDTO.class)
                    .fields("id", "id")
                    .fields("name", "name")
                    .fields("midName", "midName")
                    .fields("surname", "surname")
                    .exclude("password")
                    .fields("phone", "phone")
                    .fields("email", "email")
                    .fields("address", "address")
                    .fields("idCardNumber", "idCardNumber")
                    .fields("idCardIssueDate", "idCardIssueDate")
                    .fields("idCardExpirationDate", "idCardExpirationDate")
                    .fields("bankAccounts", "bankAccounts")
                    .fields("accountManager", "accountManager")
                    .fields("debitCardNumber", "debitCardNumber")
                    .fields("creditCardNumber", "creditCardNumber")
                    .fields("dateCreated", "dateCreated")
                    .fields("dateUpdated", "dateUpdated");
        }
    };

    @Autowired
    public ClientMapper(DozerBeanMapper mapper) {
        super(mapper);
        mapper.addMapping(builder);
    }

    public ClientDTO toDto(Client entity) {
        log.info("Mapping Client entity to DTO");
        return mapper.map(entity, ClientDTO.class);
    }

    public Client toEntity(ClientDTO dto) {
        log.info("Mapping Client DTO to entity");
        return mapper.map(dto, Client.class);
    }

    public List<ClientDTO> toDtos(List<Client> entities) {
        log.info("Mapping Client entities to DTOs");
        return entities.stream()
                       .map(entity -> toDto(entity))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Client> toEntities(List<ClientDTO> dtos) {
        log.info("Mapping Client DTOs to entities");
        return dtos.stream()
                   .map(dto -> toEntity(dto))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public EmployeeDTO toEmployeeDto(Employee entity) {
        log.info("Mapping Employee entity to DTO");
        return mapper.map(entity, EmployeeDTO.class);
    }

    public Employee toEmployeeEntity(EmployeeDTO dto) {
        log.info("Mapping Employee DTO to entity");
        return mapper.map(dto, Employee.class);
    }

    public List<EmployeeDTO> toEmployeeDtos(List<Employee> entities) {
        log.info("Mapping Employee entities to DTOs");
        return entities.stream()
                .map(entity -> toEmployeeDto(entity))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Employee> toEmployeeEntities(List<EmployeeDTO> dtos) {
        log.info("Mapping Employee DTOs to entities");
        return dtos.stream()
                .map(dto -> toEmployeeEntity(dto))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Despite this I get the following exception:

```
"httpStatus": "500 Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
    "message": "setAttribute(name, value):\n  name: "http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema\"\n  value: \"true\"",
    "stackTrace": [
        "oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory.setAttribute(JXDocumentBuilderFactory.java:289)",
    "org.dozer.loader.xml.XMLParserFactory.createDocumentBuilderFactory(XMLParserFactory.java:71)",
        "org.dozer.loader.xml.XMLParserFactory.createParser(XMLParserFactory.java:50)",
        "org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingStreamReader.<init>(MappingStreamReader.java:43)",
        "org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingFileReader.<init>(MappingFileReader.java:44)",
        "org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadFromFiles(DozerBeanMapper.java:219)",
        "org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:209)",
        "org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.initMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:315)",
        "org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:192)",
        "org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)",
        "com.rosenhristov.bank.exception.mapper.ClientMapper.toDto(ClientMapper.java:52)",
       "com.rosenhristov.bank.service.ClientService.lambda$getClientById$0(ClientService.java:27)",
        "java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)",
        "com.rosenhristov.bank.service.ClientService.getClientById(ClientService.java:27)",
        "com.rosenhristov.bank.controller.ClientController.getClientById(ClientController.java:57)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
        "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)",
        "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)",
        "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)",
        "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)",
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)",
        "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)",
        "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)",
        "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)",
        "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)",
        "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)",
        "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)",
        "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)",
        "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)",
        "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)",
        "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)",
        "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)",
        "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)",
        "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)",
        "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)",
        "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)"
]
```

It seems Dozer is trying to find some xml conffig file taking into account this:

> "oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory.setAttribute(JXDocumentBuilderFactory.java:289)"

It seems it is searching for a xml validation schema (take a look at `var1` on the picture below):

[image]

When I start the application I just saw the following in the IntelliJ console:

```
Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
2020-12-23 11:46:09.855  WARN 17488 --- [  restartedMain] org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings: Dozer configuration file not found: dozer.properties.  Using defaults for all Dozer global properties.
```

Probably I have to search for `dozer.properties` and find out how to make it look for Java configurations?

Can someone help me, please? I searched for some solution in internet but I still haven't found a suitable one. I am new to Dozer, I have used Mapstruct before?

Comment: What version of Dozer is this?  Have you tried the latest release 6.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife) to generate the dto file automatically. It will has a read method to convert the entity to dto. Although no converter from dto to entity, I think you don't need it in most situation.

```java
@ViewOf(value = Client.class, genName = "ClientDto", includePattern = ".*")
class ClientDtoConfiguration {}
```

Then it will generate a dto class named "ClientDto" with all the properties of Client.

```
Client client = ...
ClientDto clientDto = ClientDto.read(client);
List<Client> clients = ...
List<ClientDto> clientDtos = ClientDto.read(clients);
```

Then serialize the dtos instead of entities.